# LWJGL - Rotation and movement = problems

Tags: java, rotation, logic, 2d, lwjgl

Long story short, I'm making an LWJGL engine, and am drawing a basic QUAD. When I draw this QUAD and use the Keyboard listener, it moves perfectly, up/down/left/right.

When I translate and rotate however, it also pivots around its center point just fine, use both of them together, and then you have a problem. Rotation starts to go off axis, and everytime you move, you pivot around a strange point somewhere else.

How can I make it so I can move the QUAD (not relative to rotation), aswell as rotate it?

**Edit 1**

I have found out that a major problem with this QUAD, is that when I goto rotate it, my entire screen, (text included) rotates...

***My current results:***

Before Movement
[image: Before movement.]

After Movement (Hopefully you notice that it moved in a circle, instead of just LEFT when I move LEFT.)
[image: After Movement.]

***Code:***

(Display Setup)

```
try {
    Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width, height));
    Display.setVSyncEnabled(vsync);
    Display.create();
    open = true;

    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    // Sets (0, 0) to the top left corner.
    GL11.glOrtho(0, this.width, this.height, 0, 1, -1);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
} catch (LWJGLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

(Keyboard listener)

```
public void userLogic() {
    if (keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)) {
        rect.setLocation(rect.x - 1, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
        rect.setRotation(-1);
    } else if (keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)) {
        rect.setLocation(rect.x + 1, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
        rect.setRotation(1);
    } if (keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W)) {
        rect.setLocation(rect.x, rect.y - 1, rect.width, rect.height);
    } else if (keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S)) {
        rect.setLocation(rect.x, rect.y + 1, rect.width, rect.height);
    }
}
```

(Movement/Rotation Logic)

```
public void setRotation(float degrees) {
    // TODO: Fix whatever the hell the problem is here.
    GL11.glTranslatef(x + (width / 2), y/* + (height / 2)*/, 0);
    GL11.glRotatef(degrees, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    GL11.glTranslatef(-(x + (width / 2)), -(y/* + (height / 2)*/), 0);
}

public void setLocation(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}
```

(Drawing the QUAD, (detached from rest of the rendering process))

```
public void render() {
    switch(type) {
    case IMAGE:
        // Not ready yet.
        break;
    case TRIANGLE:
        // Not ready yet.
        break;
    case RECTANGLE:
        GL11.glColor3f(colour.red, colour.green, colour.blue);

        // X, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT are the QUADS coords, not the displays or anything else's.

        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x, y);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + width, y);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x + width, y + height);
            GL11.glVertex2f(x, y + height);
        GL11.glEnd();
        break;
    }
}
```

Any help will be gratefully appreciated, if you are going to downvote, please give a reason so I can improve this question, or even better, comment instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the order in which you call the translate and rotate functions of OpenGL in your `setRotation`function . The order of calling must be Translation(if any)-> Rotation(if any)->Scaling. You cannot change this order of calling or mix them up in anyway. Or else you'll not get the desired results. This is because the way in which these commands are processed internally by OpenGL.

Change your `SetRotation` function to

```
public void setRotation(float degrees) {
    // TODO: Fix whatever the hell the problem is here.
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glTranslatef(x , y , 0);       
    GL11.glRotatef(degrees, 0f, 0f, 1f);

}
```

You'll notice that if you add the lines

```
GL11.glTranslatef(x , y, 0);
```

underneath

```
GL11.glRotatef(degrees, 0f, 0f, 1f);
```

, the result will be completely different. Meaning the order is important.

There are some problems in the `userLogic()`function as well. In this case, you need to create a global variable to store rotation and then pass it to `setRotation()`

```
float rotValue = 0;
public void userLogic() {
    if (keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)) {
        rect.setLocation(rect.x - 1, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
        rotValue-=.1f;
        rotValue=rotValue<0?rotValue+360:rotValue;
        rect.setRotation(rotValue);
    } else if (keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)) {
        rect.setLocation(rect.x + 1, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
        rotValue+=.1f;
        rotValue=rotValue>=360?rotValue-360:rotValue;
        rect.setRotation(rotValue);
    } if (keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W)) {
        rect.setLocation(rect.x, rect.y - 1, rect.width, rect.height);
    } else if (keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S)) {
        rect.setLocation(rect.x, rect.y + 1, rect.width, rect.height);
    }
}
```

Finally inside the `render()` function, pass in vertices centered around (0,0). glTranslatef will take care of translation.

```
case RECTANGLE:
        GL11.glColor3f(colour.red, colour.green, colour.blue);
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glVertex2f(-width/2, -height/2);
        GL11.glVertex2f(width/2, -height/2);
        GL11.glVertex2f(width/2, height/2);
        GL11.glVertex2f(-width/2, height/2);
        GL11.glEnd();
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW); //resetting the rotation
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();  //and translation so that other
                                //objects are unaffected
            break;
```

Here is a simple lwjgl project I made showcasing translation and rotation of a quad and triangle
https://gist.github.com/Coditivity/0eedc86447a509f6b5ef

Comment: This doesn't work. All this does is rotates it from the top-left of my entire screen. I also have a problem that it doesn't just rotate the square, it rotates EVERYTHING on my screen!

Comment: This is because your resetting the translation before anything is done. Therefore, there is no point in adding any of the code if I do it like that.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Now it should work. You need to change the active matrix to MODEL_VIEW and initialize it to an identity matrix. Since those translations are cancelling each other, you should get a rotating square.

Comment: Hmmm... Nothing has changed.... I created an `int` called rotation, and made it *also* equal the degrees I want to change by. So it still rotates, but still from the origin...

Comment: I'v added some final fixes. This code runs fine on the test lwjgl project I made. I should have tested the code I posted earlier, apologies.

Comment: Thankyou, will take a look now... Just modified a whole part of the engine, (Non-render specific), so I'll just have to patch that part up.

Comment: Oh jeez, I really appreciate your help, but for some reason it just isn't working. I removed that translate line like you did, everything is the same infact, but it just doesn't seem to want to work.

Comment: I'm **really** close, the square is rotating fine, but everything else around it still rotates. Any ideas? (I can do an EDIT with my current code if you like)

Comment: You need to render rectangle first, then the rest of the objects. Meaning the part under `case RECTANGLE:`should be executed before the draw calls (`glBegin` part) of any other object.

Comment: I forgot to add, you need to call glLoadIdentity, glTranslatef,glRotatef and glScalef on all objects you are going to draw. You can see it action in the link I posted

Comment: I have terrible internet at the moment, and am having horrible issues, unable to reply. I have reluctantly chosen to use Shaders instead, but appreciate all the amazing help you have given me. Thankyou.